# Xamarin iOS 7 - TableHeader added to DialogViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am converting an app based on Monotouch.Dialog to iOS 7.

The app runs fine, but the tables that are created appear 1cm down, a space appears at the top. (see image with grey leather texture). How can I turn that space off so that the table is nice and flush with the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the space was the Section() of a DialogViewController. When I put text into the section it appears.

Switched from Group to Plain as a table style.

I had tried all the options at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios7_ui/ which did help a bit in reducing he space, but the Section() in iOS7 tripped me up.

It's working great now.

Xamarin is an amazing toolset.